# Можно ли так писать в PHP?

Tags: php

Нужно показывать HTML-код при определенном условии. Правильно ли так писать?

```
<?php if ($time == 1) { ?>
    <div class="coming_soon">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <p>Здесь скоро появится новый урок...</p>
    </div>
<?php }; ?>
```

Всё работает, но почему-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: можно. только не используют фигурные скобки в шаблонах. для этого есть специальные сокращения (не помню как они правильно называются) `<?php if ($time == 1) : ?>` и закрывать как `<?php endif; ?>`   или `<?php foreach ($time as $item) : ?>` и закрывать как `<?php endforeach; ?>` и так далее...чтоб видно было соответствие между собой............http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский используют фигурные скобки. Мы от endif всяких избавляемся, это же бейсик какой-то.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр этот синтаксис чуть ли не специально создан как раз-таки для шаблона.  Использование скобок в шаблоне также глупо, т.к. их сложно уследить при разрыве, тем более когда может быть несколько вложенностей разнесенных довольно далеко. В голом коде, а-ля контроллер, к примеру такой синтаксис абсолютно не нужен и идиотичен, да. Но в шаблонах все как раз наоборот. Так что вы не правы. Причем категорически

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  я не могу быть не правым - т.к. это на вкус и цвет, то есть является мнением. У нас таки все сошлись на том, что фигурные скобки гораздо элегантнее и короче в том числе в шаблонах. А `т.к. их сложно уследить при разрыве` - да нет уж, любое IDE давно это подсвечивет, ткните после фигурной скобки, увидите конец. Да и с кем общался - бейсика в видах никто не хочет, вообще в первый раз вижу того, кому нравится `endif;` :)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр `я не могу быть не правым - т.к. это на вкус и цвет`.... это противоречие, так то на секундочку ;-)     ...... вы можете внутри компании договариваться о чем угодно, хоть о вставке рисунков енота юникодом между строк. Это не делает его  общепринятой практикой. Если смотреть в запросах поисковика "альтернативный синтаксис php" вы не увидите в ответах на запрос фигурных скобок, потому что распространенная практика другая.  В т.ч.  http://php.net показывает именно эту практику (через endforeach и пр.)...в общем я высказался

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский никакого противоречия, я ещё раз говорю что это мнение - которое не может быть верным или неверным априори. Как выяснилось - в подсознании нечто, выделенное фигурными скобками через несколько строчек гораздо больше похоже на блок, нежели if(..): ... endif; )  А согласись, приятно воспринимать код - не набором символов, а впитывать подсознанием? А то что показывает php.net без логики не принимается, могло когда-то быть актуальным, и ныне устаревшим. И я высказался :)

Comment: как раз фигурные наглядно показывают разрывы, а бейсиковые endif вообще ничего не показывают. в битриксе смотрю добра этого навалом, ясно откуда дровишки)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от Вашего стиля программирования и используемых паттернов. Способов вывести HTML много. Лучше всего что бы в Вашем приложении придерживался **единый** стиль.

Я предпочитаю выводить `HTML` так:

```
echo <<<HTML
    div class="coming_soon">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <p>Здесь скоро появится новый урок...</p>
    </div>
HTML;
```

Это помогает при навигации по файлам. Достаточно включить поиск по `<<<HTML`.

Но если Вы используете паттерн `MVC`, то логика должна быть отдельна, а вьюшки отдельно. Так как часто верстальщик не знает `PHP` и наоборот.

Часть `PHP` файла контролерра:

```
<?php
if ($time == 1) {
return include $this->viewsPath.'_comming_soon.php';
}
```

Вьюшка `_comming_soon.php`:

```
<div class="coming_soon">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p>Здесь скоро появится новый урок...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: на каждый чих вьюшки создавать?))) Которая нужна будет один несчастный раз??? Оооо

Comment: @СергейВ. Право Ваше. Но блогадаря Вашему подходу PHP не когда не разовется до уровня ++, джавы или шарпа.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно. Вот еще пример:

```
<?php if ($time == 1): ?>
    <div class="coming_soon">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <p>Здесь скоро появится новый урок...</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```